# Opening Foursquare Android application on specific user profile

Tags: android, android-intent, foursquare

I am trying to open Foursquare application from my Android application on a given user profile.
I followed the official documentation : 
https://developer.foursquare.com/resources/client#android

I've created an Intent of type `ACTION_VIEW` and gave the URI such as `http://m.foursquare.com/user?uid=USER_ID`, with the ID of the profile I want to see :

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://m.foursquare.com/user?uid=USER_ID");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Executing on Android, 2.3.3 and 4.2.2, I get the following behavior : the intent chooser appears and ask me the way to finish the action (Foursquare or Browser). When clicking on "Foursquare", I see the application appears and disappears immediately.

I can see in log cat that the Intent is started. Then, the `onResume` method of my Fragment is called with no explanation of Foursquare failure :

```
03-04 14:40:55.305: I/ActivityManager(2690): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://m.foursquare.com/user?uid=USER_ID flg=0x3800000 cmp=com.joelapenna.foursquared/.BrowsableActivity } from pid 2690
03-04 14:40:55.320: I/OrientationDebug(2690): [pwm] in updateOrientationListenerLp()
03-04 14:40:55.320: V/OrientationDebug(2690): in updateOrientationListenerLp(), Screen status=true, current orientation=-1, SensorEnabled=true
03-04 14:40:55.320: I/OrientationDebug(2690): [pwm] needSensorRunningLp(), return true #4
03-04 14:40:55.320: W/ActivityManager(2690): Trying to launch com.joelapenna.foursquared/.BrowsableActivity
03-04 14:40:55.355: E/ResourceType(4814): Style contains key with bad entry: 0x010102f3
03-04 14:40:55.355: E/ResourceType(4814): Style contains key with bad entry: 0x0101030b
03-04 14:40:55.355: E/ResourceType(4814): Style contains key with bad entry: 0x01010397
03-04 14:40:55.355: E/ResourceType(4814): Style contains key with bad entry: 0x0101039c
03-04 14:40:55.410: D/szipinf(4814): Initializing inflate state
03-04 14:40:55.420: I/OrientationDebug(2690): [pwm] in updateOrientationListenerLp()
03-04 14:40:55.420: V/OrientationDebug(2690): in updateOrientationListenerLp(), Screen status=true, current orientation=1, SensorEnabled=true
03-04 14:40:55.420: I/OrientationDebug(2690): [pwm] needSensorRunningLp(), return true #4
03-04 14:40:55.445: D/MyFragment(6374): onResume
```

When creating an Intent of type `ACTION_VIEW` with URI like `foursquare://users/USER_ID`, it launches the Foursquare application but stay on my profile screen, not on the given profile.

Any idea ?

Comment: Does FourSquare offer some kind of support?

Comment: users or user? The URL looks like this, http: //m.foursquare.com/user?uid=USER_ID

Comment: @codingcrow In the [Foursquare official documentation](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/support), they specify to use stackoverflow for questions on the API.

Comment: Wait for sometime they should come and answer your question. In the meantime you can think of ways to improve the question. Also you can tweet them to get their attention @foursquareAPI.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, these Intents do appear to currently not work as intended. Our engineers are working to fix this, and we'll keep you updated.

If you need a solution immediately, perhaps open the user's profile in a WebView? (e.g., https://foursquare.com/user/620652)

Comment: You can expect this to be fixed in the next release.